# How to add elements of tuple in a list together?

Tags: python, tuples

I have a list of tuples over here:

```
myList = [('2012-01-01', '09:00', 'San Jose', "Men's Clothing", '214.05', 'Amex'), 
          ('2012-01-01', '09:00', 'Fort Worth', "Women's Clothing", '153.57', 'Visa'), 
          ('2012-01-01', '09:00', 'San Diego', 'Music', '66.08', 'Cash')]
```

And I've used this to access the 5th element which is the price of the item,

```
for x in range(len(myList)):
    sales = myList[x][4]
print(sales)
```

I've tried adding the prices by doing this, but it doesn't work:

```
for x in range(len(myList)):
    sales += myList[x][4]
print(sales)
```

The error:

```
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'totalSales' referenced before assignment
```

My question is: How to add them up properly?

Comment: What does "doesn't work" mean?

Comment: i got this as the error `UnboundLocalError: local variable 'totalSales' referenced before assignment` @Code-Apprentice

Comment: you need to give your counter an initial value: `sales = 0`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a [**list comprehension**](http://treyhunner.com/2015/12/python-list-comprehensions-now-in-color/), **[sum](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#sum)** & **[float](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#float)** method to get your result

```
myList = [('2012-01-01', '09:00', 'San Jose', "Men's Clothing", '214.05', 'Amex'), 
          ('2012-01-01', '09:00', 'Fort Worth', "Women's Clothing", '153.57', 'Visa'), 
          ('2012-01-01', '09:00', 'San Diego', 'Music', '66.08', 'Cash')]

print sum(float(i[4]) for i in myList)
```

**Result**:

```
433.7
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not working because that item is a string, not a number. You can convert it to float and it should work

```
sales = 0
for x in range(len(myList)):
    sales += float(myList[x][4])
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following one-line solution with built-in [`sum()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sum):

```
sales = sum(float(item[4]) for item in myList)
```

**Output:**

```
>>> sales = sum(float(item[4]) for item in myList)
>>> sales
433.7
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to initialize the `sales` variable and add to it the `float` value of each string as you loop through the list of tuples.

```
myList = [('2012-01-01', '09:00', 'San Jose', "Men's Clothing", '214.05', 'Amex'), 
          ('2012-01-01', '09:00', 'Fort Worth', "Women's Clothing", '153.57', 'Visa'), 
          ('2012-01-01', '09:00', 'San Diego', 'Music', '66.08', 'Cash')]

sales = 0

for x in range(len(myList)):
    sales += float(myList[x][4])

print(sales)
# 433.7
```

You could do it without `range()` and `len()` in the loop:

```
sales = 0

for tup in myList:
    sales += float(tup[4])

print(sales)
# 433.7
```

You could also use a generator expression:

```
print(sum(float(tup[4]) for tup in myList))
# 433.7
```